# Tkinter Text scroll lag issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this super simple implementation of a textBox:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1650x900')
center_windows(root)
root.resizable(0, 0)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
old_xml_text = Text(root, wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, height=40, width=60)    
old_xml_text.grid(row=0, column=0,pady=(100,0),padx=(50,50),sticky='we')    
scrollbar.config(command=old_xml_text.yview)
```

The problem is that if I paste there a long text (2k lines) it became extremely laggy during scrolling.

How can I solve this?

If there is no solution using `Tkinter`, is there any other way to achieve this using other package (in Python)? I don't want any kind of lag when I past or scroll the text. Am I forced to use C/C++ ?

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: I can't find a problem with your code. I think the problem is in tcl/the windows scroll bar

Comment: Updated the post, thx

Comment: Yes, it is laggy. If you paste thousands of lines with word wrapping, it takes some time to even compute the number of lines that will be created. Only then, the scrolling may be bound to the text. It's the same in the IDLE console. If the output is too large, you get laggy scrolling. Using a fixed space font and character wrapping speeds things up a little. But it remains slow.

Comment: Thanks @MartinWettstein, I updated the post with another question. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to make it less laggy: If the text inserted to the text widget does not use the word wrapper of the Text widget for line breaks, the lag is practically absent. So, you just have to preprocess your text to teh effect that no line is longer than 40 characters (the width of your Text widget). The preprocessing may take some seconds, but it's worth it. As far as I can see, you are trying to display XML, where it should not be a problem to have frequent line breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the computation time it takes the Text widget to insert all line breaks and thereby to compute the total number of lines and the current position. While scrolling, this computation is too slow and you get lags and the scrollbar is rendered useless.

If you want to speed it up and remove the lags, you have to insert line breaks manually, so that no line extends the 60 character width of your text window. If you insert line breaks and don't pass it to the wrapper, it won't lag. See the following example for reference:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
#center_windows(root)
root.resizable(0, 0)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
old_xml_text = Text(root, wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, width=60,height=10)    
old_xml_text.grid(row=0, column=0,pady=(100,0),padx=(0,0),sticky=N+S+E)    
scrollbar.config(command=old_xml_text.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=(100,0),sticky=N+S+W)

scrollbar2 = Scrollbar(root)
old_xml_text2 = Text(root, wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set, width=60,height=10)    
old_xml_text2.grid(row=2, column=0,pady=(100,0),padx=(0,0),sticky=N+S+E)    
scrollbar2.config(command=old_xml_text2.yview)
scrollbar2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=(100,0),sticky=N+S+W)


old_xml_text.insert(END,"Hello World, this is a test of reaction times\n"*1000)
old_xml_text2.insert(END,"Hello World, this is a test of reaction times"*1000)
```

You can see that the Text widget with line breaks is perfectly well scrollable while the one that uses the Text widget wrapper is not.

Comment: Fantastic! Is there a way to achieve this without preprocessing the text? Or to process that directly in `Python` code? thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, I would definitely recommend preprocessing it in python. After all, it's just a matter of splitting the string to pieces of up to 60 chars and joining it with newlines. That should not be a problem. It might be difficult if you want legible XML structure with correct indentation, but that's very well possible in pyhton.